# One record from multiple records in the table

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where ID has three flags. 
For example

```
ID flag1 flag2 flag3 
1  0     1     0
2  1     0     0
1  1     0     0
1  0     0     1
2  0     1     0
3  0     1     0
4  1     0     0
```

Now I want the records having flag2=1 only.. I.e ID=3 has flag2=1 where as ID = 1 and 2 has flag1 and flag3 =1 along with flag2=1. I don't want ID=1 and 2. 
I can't make ID unique or primary. I tried with case when statements but it I am somehow missing the basic logic. 
We can do it with CTE but I want to repeat this for three different scenarios(Same logic I want to repeat for ID=4 where Flag1=1 only).

Comment: I doubt you are using both MySQL and SQL Server.  Please tag your question with the *one* database you are using.

Comment: your explanation is confusing to me. you mean, you want only IDs, where each entry/line of the ID has flag2==1? so in your example, only ID=3?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow didn't know how to use it.I want ID's where flag2=1 only.. in my example it is ID=3. ID=1 also has flag2 as 1 but it also has flag1=1 which I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ids with this condition using `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having min(flag2) = max(flag2) and min(flag2) = 1;
```